# How to arrange text views in JetpackCompose next to each other and break the one that reaches the max screen width to a new line?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to accomplish the same as this image in jetpack compose, I need to arrange a list of texts next to each other and break the rest of the string to a new line if needed.

[image: Need to do the same as this1]

I have tried *FlowRow* and *FlowColumn* but it does NOT accomplish what I need, as it does not break the reminder string to the next line, if the reminder space is smaller than the width of the Text composable.

I can concat all the strings into one string and create one Text composable, but I need to deal with each String as a separate Text Composable for further functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve the behaviour you want using several `Text()` Composables, as each Composable will consume a rectangular block of space.

You could however display the texts in a single Composable and then for example discern click events on the different paragraphs of the text. 
Have a look at the [AnnotatedString](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/user-interactions#get-click-position) functionality and [classes](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder#pushStringAnnotation(kotlin.String,kotlin.String)) of Jetpack Compose. Using them, you can display and style text within in a single `Text()` Composable and detect and discern clicks on each annotated section of the String that is displayed. An implementation that could fit your needs is shown below:

```
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {

    pushStringAnnotation(tag = "colorType", annotation = " --> red")
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color(0xff0000))) {
        append("red - text - red - text - red - text - red - text - red")
    }
    pop()

    pushStringAnnotation(tag = "colorType", annotation = " --> blue")

    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color(0x0000ff))) {
        append("blue - text - blue - text - blue - text - blue - text")
    }
    pop()
}

ClickableText(text = annotatedString, onClick = { offset ->
    annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(tag = "colorType", start = offset, end = offset).firstOrNull()?.let {
        Log.d("Color of clicked text is -->", it.item)
    }
})
```

When you now click on the red section of the text, it should print

```
Color of clicked text is --> --> red
```